# ajax of type PUT or POST in UIWebView does not pass HTTP body

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I am opening a simple HTML document inside UIWebView in my app:

```
<h3>Testing Put</h3>
<form id="testPut" action="onPut">
    <div>
        <p><input type="text" id="putValue" name="putValue" value="some value string goes here" size="100"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit via PUT"/></p>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
$('#testPut').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var value = $('#putValue').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "data/info/put",
        contentType: "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
        data: encodeURIComponent(value),
        dataType: "text"
    });
});
</script>
```

For the sake of simplicity I omitted success and error handlers from the code as my problem is not related to really replying to the request.

I am using jQuery 1.10.2 however I get exactly the same results when using pure `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Since this is known issue that Ajax requests cannot be caught by `UIWebViewDelegate` methods, I decided to create a quite simple descendant of `NSURLProtocol` and register it in my controller's `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
@implementation MyProtocol

+ (BOOL)canInitWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    // only "data/info" requests are welcome
    NSRange range = [[request.URL absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"data/info"];
    return NSNotFound != range.location;
}

+ (NSURLRequest *)canonicalRequestForRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request {
    return request;
}

- (void)startLoading {
    NSURLRequest *request = self.request;

    NSLog(@"%@", request);
    NSLog(@"Headers: %@", [request allHTTPHeaderFields]);
    NSLog(@"Method: %@", [request HTTPMethod]);
    NSLog(@"Body: %@", [request HTTPBody]);
}

- (void)stopLoading {}

@end
```

Then I run the app, tap "Submit via PUT" button and observe the following in console log of Xcode:

```
2013-10-31 16:38:28.077 TestHTTPPUTiOS[1608:4a03] <NSURLRequest: 0x8942c20> { URL: file:///Users/oradyvanyuk/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/90232D0E-3243-4517-A2B7-15A17371E117/TestHTTPPUTiOS.app/data/info/put }
2013-10-31 16:38:28.079 TestHTTPPUTiOS[1608:4a03] Headers: {
    Accept = "text/plain, */*; q=0.01";
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
    Origin = "file://";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
}
2013-10-31 16:38:28.079 TestHTTPPUTiOS[1608:4a03] Method: PUT
2013-10-31 16:38:28.080 TestHTTPPUTiOS[1608:4a03] Body: (null)
```

As you can see, the HTTP request body is empty. I've tried using POST method and got exactly the same output, with the only difference of `Method: POST` in console.

When using GET method, I also get empty HTTP body, but this is in fact expected since the `putValue` string from the form arrives in HTTP request's URL.

Could you please advise on this issue or at least tell me if I am doing something wrong? I need to obtain the passed value as HTTP body content and not in URL since it may be quite long.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following for your AJAX call?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "data/info/put",
    data: 'key='+encodeURIComponent(value),
    dataType: "text"
});
```

I tried a bunch of combinations and settings with your specific example, and this was the only one that reliably sent the data as expected (i.e. by removing the contentType specification and changing the request type to POST from PUT).  Also, note that PUT is not supported on all browsers, so unless there is some critical reason to use it instead of POST, you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Just tried what you suggested and it does not work as well. Whatever you specify in "data" attribute simply does not get its way to the HTTP body where it should be. And it does not matter what is the value of "contentType" if specified at all.

Comment: I suspect there is an bug in WebKit implementation. I already posted a bug report to Apple's bugtracker and so far it is still in the Open state. I hope the issue will get fixed in the upcoming releases of iOS.